# iptables doesn't want to log and drop simultaneously

Tags: iptables, logging, flags, dropped

I'm (still) trying to build an iptables firewall, but this time, I'm stuck trying to log dropped packets. Here is how I'm doing this (this code is inserted after the `ACCEPT` rules; `$IPT` represents the absolute path to iptables, here `/sbin/iptables`):

```
$IPT -N LOGDROP
$IPT -A LOGDROP -j LOG -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix "iptables rejected: "
$IPT -A LOGDROP -j DROP
$IPT -A INPUT -s 0/0 -j LOGDROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -j LOGDROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -j LOGDROP
```

When I try to execute this code, iptables rejects it, saying :

```
iptables v1.4.8: multiple -j flags not allowed
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

And yet, I saw everywhere on the web that this is the way to apply two actions on selected packets, so why is my iptables version in such a bad mood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified `-j LOG` twice in this line:

```
$IPT -A LOGDROP -j LOG -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix "iptables rejected: "
```

Comment: Aw f*ck... Please excuse my stupidity.